# Moving Picture box with timer faster

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I have a project in Compact framework 2.0 C#
I am using a lot of picturebox in Form and there is a timer to change the location of pictureboxs every second but moving is very slowly how can I make faster it?

Timer interval is 100

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  picust.Location = new Point(picust.Location.X, picust.Location.Y + 10);
  picx.Location = new Point(picx.Location.X, picx.Location.Y + 10);
  picy.Location = new Point(picy.Location.X, picx.Location.Y + 10);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried lowering the interval of the timer?

Comment: @MedMik I have to use hight interval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using NET Compact Framework 2.0 you could improve your code by using [`SuspendLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout.aspx) and [`ResumeLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y53zat12.aspx) methods which are supported starting from version 2.0. Put these methods around your code as in the example:

```
//assuming that this code is within the parent Form

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.SuspendLayout();
  picust.Location = new Point(picust.Location.X, picust.Location.Y + 10);
  picx.Location = new Point(picx.Location.X, picx.Location.Y + 10);
  picy.Location = new Point(picy.Location.X, picx.Location.Y + 10);
  this.ResumeLayout();
}
```

This will prevent three redrawings of the form and instead perform only one.

Comment: Thanks For your answer I am trying.By the way some pictureboxes are in panel control or front on the another picturebox do I have to suspend layout another controls

Comment: Whenever you SuspendLayout, you are preventing the control redrawing for each change that you made and it waits the ResumeLayout call when it redraws according to the changes you made. Therefore, you should use this concept whenever you are changing multiple controls on the same parent control.